# How create & publish a WebService using Camel?

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

Is it possible to create and publish a WebService using camel without the need of xml files?

With JAX-WS I can create a WS like

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public class CreatorWebService {

public String create(String word1, String word2, String word3) {
return Maker.make(word1, word2, word3);
}}
```

and publish it very easy with

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    CreatorWebService server = new CreatorWebService ();
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/creator", server);
}
```

How can this be done with camel and if possible with JAVA DSL and without using XML (web.xml, beans...)?

I want to use the incoming messages of this WS as input for a route like for example:

```
from(WSinputMessage).to("myProcessor").to(doSomething);
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure how you want the WS request to be parsed and how you should treat it, since there might be several ways.

Should be possible to achive a very similar setup with Camel using the [jetty component](http://camel.apache.org/jetty) and the [CXF BEAN component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf-bean-component.html)

i.e.

```
 from("jetty:http://localhost:9000/").to("cxfbean:serviceObj").to("handleReplySomehow");
     //serviceObj does not have to be a spring bean, but can be a JAX-WS annotated object in the camel registry.
```